# jQuery selector for subfield in array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, selector, field

What's the proper way for jQuery selecting a  object when the name states a subfield in an array?

I spontanously tried:

```
$('select[name=field[subfield]]').change(function(){
  alert('houston we have contact');
});
```

The DOM object is:

```
<select name="field[subfield]">
  <option>..</option>
  <option>..</option>
  <option>..</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding quotes:

```
$('select[name="field[subfield]"]').change(function(){
  alert('houston we have contact');
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hHHMS/

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with eZaktos answer. Backslash if using same quotes.

Single qoutes:

```
  $('select[name=\'field[subfield]\']').change(function(){
    alert('houston we have contact');
  });
```

Double quotes:

```
  $("select[name=\"field[subfield]\"]").change(function(){
    alert('houston we have contact');
  });
```

Double quotes and single quotes:

```
  $("select[name='field[subfield]']").change(function(){
    alert('houston we have contact');
  });
```

Single quotes and double quotes:

```
$('select[name="field[subfield]"]').change(function(){
  alert('houston we have contact');
});
```